# bokeh taptool selection colours

Tags: bokeh

I am using the `TapTool` in bokeh to select some circles which I have drawn on top of a `gmap`. Currently, the selected circle is in the foreground and the rest fade into the map background.

Is there a way to change this default behaviour? I would like, for example, to give a different colour boundary to the selected circle and keep the rest the same. Is there a way to change the rendering of the selected and unselected objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Styling Visual Attributes](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html) chapter of the User's Guide has a section specifically for [Selected and Unselected Glyphs](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#selected-and-unselected-glyphs). The easiest way is to use the convenience paramters that can be passed to the glyph methods:

```
plot.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 5, 8, 2, 7], size=50,

            # set visual properties for selected glyphs
            selection_color="firebrick",

            # set visual properties for non-selected glyphs
            nonselection_fill_alpha=0.2,
            nonselection_fill_color="blue",
            nonselection_line_color="firebrick",
            nonselection_line_alpha=1.0)
```

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the upvote. If this answers your question, an "accept" would also be appreciated (and good for the project to have answers accepted)

Comment: Yes, you were too fast and I had to wait before accepting :)