# Bokeh Server - Change color of glyph on select with Tap Tool

Tags: python, server, bokeh, interactive

I want to use the TapTool with Bokeh server to run a callback with some additional functionality.

The glyphs I want to select are on top of a background image.

If I select a glyph with the TapTool the glyph keeps its opacity but all other glyphs get reduced in opacity. The problem is that those glyphs can not be seen well on the background image when they become more opace.

Is there a way to leave the alpha values of the glyphs all at 100% and instead change the color of the selected glyphs?

Here is some example code as a start that I found [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6707)

```
from bokeh import plotting as bplt
from bokeh import layouts as blayouts
from bokeh import models as bmodels
from bokeh import io as bio

fig = bplt.figure(tools="tap")

source = bmodels.ColumnDataSource(dict(x=[0,1], y=[0,1]))

r = fig.circle('x', 'y', source=source, size=10)

def handler(attr, old, new):
    print('attr: {} old: {} new: {}'.format(attr, old, new))

# r.data_source.on_change('selected', handler)
r.data_source.selected.on_change('indices', handler)

bio.curdoc().add_root(blayouts.layout([[fig]]))
```

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58017566/bokeh-taptool-selection-colours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example for bokeh 2.0.1:

```
from bokeh import plotting as bplt
from bokeh import layouts as blayouts
from bokeh import models as bmodels
from bokeh import io as bio

fig = bplt.figure(tools="tap")

source = bmodels.ColumnDataSource(dict(x=[0,1], y=[0,1]))

r = fig.circle('x', 'y', source=source, size=10, color='#000000',
        # set visual properties for selected glyphs
                    selection_color="#2bff00",

                    # set visual properties for non-selected glyphs
                    nonselection_fill_alpha=1.0,
                    nonselection_fill_color="#000000")

def handler(attr, old, new):
    print('attr: {} old: {} new: {}'.format(attr, old, new))

# r.data_source.on_change('selected', handler)
r.data_source.selected.on_change('indices', handler)

bio.curdoc().add_root(blayouts.layout([[fig]]))
```